# iOS TableView not displaying cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, tableview

I have seen several related questions, but mine is different in that I want to do it purely in coding, so without storyboards or interface builder.

Basically I get lost in how to properly display the cells in a TableView. I have created a very simple SplitView test application. In it I try to show the same TableView twice: once in the TableViewController and once in the DetailViewController (for a user this would make little sense, but I try to grasp how to get this done).

In the TableViewController, the 3 cells show correctly, but in the DetailView, the TableView shows without the cells. There must be a simple step to have the cells drawn, but all the example cases I find assume you use storyboards or IB

In the SplitView I have:

```
- (id) init{

    self = [super init];

    JBDetailViewController *detailVC = [JBDetailViewController controller];
    UINavigationController *detailNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailVC];

    JBTableViewController *rootVC2 = [[JBTableViewController alloc] init];
    rootVC2.title = @"A TableVC title";

    UINavigationController *rootNav2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootVC2];

    self.viewControllers = @[rootNav2, detailNav];
    self.delegate = detailVC;
    self.tabBarItem.title = @"a Tab title";

return self;
```

}

In the DetailViewer I have:

```
- (void) loadView {
[super loadView];

self.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.85f];
JBTableViewController *rootVC2 = [[JBTableViewController alloc] init];
[rootVC2 loadView];
rootVC2.title = @"Test van Justus";

rootVC2.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor yellowColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.85f];

[self.view addSubview:rootVC2.view];
```

}

Both use the same JBTableViewController that is very simple and should display 3 cells, which it does in the VC, but not in the DetailView.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: did you implement `UITableViewDataSource`?

Comment: Yes I did. I found the solution, I had to link the ViewController of the childview to the parent view:  
      [self addChildViewController:rootVC2];
      [self.view addSubview:rootVC2.view];